# Imprimir documento desde Java eligiendo impresora

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de imprimir documentos de tipo .docx (opcionalmente si se puede tambien en .doc o .pdf). Los archivos son generados por un programa en java 
 ,y este los guarda en una carpeta especifica. Tengo este fragmento de código que si bien cumple la función de imprimir lo veo limitado.

```
File doc = new File("c:\\Documentos\\prueba.docx");
Desktop.getDesktop().print(doc);
```

El código manda a imprimir por medio de Word (en Windows) el cual abre y ejecuta la acción de imprimir y luego cierra. Lo que quiero es que me aparezca una ventana para poder seleccionar la impresora a usar de varias que tengo conectadas a mi red.

Nota: Considerar que se usara Linux con LibreOffice en el servidor, asi que el uso de alguna `dll` complicaría las cosas.